# How Can I put the LabelFrames of my Tkinter Python Script to the same level?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Im creating my first python GUI and im working with Tkinter

i added a bunch of labelframes and inside of them are different numbers of radiobuttons

One of them has 3 radiobuttons instead of 2 and its not on the same level as the other ones.
[the created gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOnMl.png)

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

top = tk.Tk()
top.resizable(True, True)

# General Category
GenInfoLabel = tk.LabelFrame(top,text="General Information", fg="blue")
GenInfoLabel.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=10, pady=5)

# One
One_Frame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel,text="One", fg="blue")
One_Frame.grid(column=1, row=1)

def One_Call():
    One_Sel=One_Var.get()
    if      One_Sel == 1: One_ = 1
    elif    One_Sel == 2: One_ = 2

One_Var = tk.IntVar()

rad_One_V1 = tk.Radiobutton(One_Frame, text="1", variable = One_Var, value=1, command=One_Call)
rad_One_V1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

rad_One_V2 = tk.Radiobutton(One_Frame, text="2", variable = One_Var, value=2, command=One_Call)
rad_One_V2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# Two
Two_Frame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel , text="Two", fg="blue")
Two_Frame.grid(column=2, row=1)

def Two_Call():
    Two_Sel=Two_Var.get()
    if      Two_Sel == 1: Two_ = 1
    elif    Two_Sel == 2: Two_ = 2
Two_Var = tk.IntVar()
rad_Two_1 = tk.Radiobutton(Two_Frame, text="1", variable = Two_Var, value=1, command=Two_Call)
rad_Two_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

rad_Two_2 = tk.Radiobutton(Two_Frame, text="2", variable = Two_Var, value=2, command=Two_Call)
rad_Two_2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# Three
ThreeFrame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel, text="Three", fg="blue")
ThreeFrame.grid(column=3, row=1)

def ThreeCall():
    ThreeSel=ThreeVar.get()
    if      ThreeSel == 1: Three = 1
    elif    ThreeSel == 2: Three = 2
ThreeVar = tk.IntVar()

radThree1 = tk.Radiobutton(ThreeFrame, text="Yes", variable = ThreeVar, value=1, command=ThreeCall)
radThree1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radThree2 = tk.Radiobutton(ThreeFrame, text="No", variable = ThreeVar, value=2, command=ThreeCall)
radThree2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# Four
FourFrame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel, text="Four", fg="blue")
FourFrame.grid(column=4, row=1)

def FourCall():
    FourSel=FourVar.get()
    if      FourSel == 1: Four = 1
    elif    FourSel == 2: Four = 2
FourVar = tk.IntVar()

radFour1 = tk.Radiobutton(FourFrame, text="1", variable = FourVar, value=1, command=FourCall)
radFour1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radFour2 = tk.Radiobutton(FourFrame, text="2", variable = FourVar, value=2, command=FourCall)
radFour2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# Five
FiveFrame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel, text="Five", fg="blue")
FiveFrame.grid(column=5, row=1)

def FiveCall():
    FiveSel=FiveVar.get()
    if      FiveSel == 1: Five = 1
    elif    FiveSel == 2: Five = 2
    elif    FiveSel == 3: Five = 3
FiveVar = tk.IntVar()

radFive1 = tk.Radiobutton(FiveFrame, text="1", variable = FiveVar, value=1, command=FiveCall)
radFive1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radFive2 = tk.Radiobutton(FiveFrame, text="2", variable = FiveVar, value=2, command=FiveCall)
radFive2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radFive3 = tk.Radiobutton(FiveFrame, text="3", variable = FiveVar, value=3, command=FiveCall)
radFive3.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

# Six
SixFrame = tk.LabelFrame(GenInfoLabel, text="Six", fg="blue")
SixFrame.grid(column=6, row=1)

def SixCall():
    SixSel=SixVar.get()
    if      SixSel == 1: Six = 1
    elif    SixSel == 2: Six = 2
SixVar = tk.IntVar()

radSix1 = tk.Radiobutton(SixFrame, text="1", variable = SixVar, value=1, command=SixCall)
radSix1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

radSix2 = tk.Radiobutton(SixFrame, text="2", variable = SixVar, value=2, command=SixCall)
radSix2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, columnspan=3)

for child in GenInfoLabel.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=8)
# Display Form
top.mainloop()
```

How can i edit the code so they are aligned?

Sincerely Pascal

tried to use the height function without results or changing the paddings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `sticky='n'` to each of the `grid()` calls for the 5 `LabelFrame` widgets so they'll all "stick" to the top of their parent frame

**FYI**: the `'n'` here refers to "North", or the top of the containing widget/window. You can also use other cardinal directions with `'sticky'`, like `'ne'`, `'w'`, `'sw'`. You can even expand across an axis with `'ew'` or `'ns'`, and you can also `'center'` objects on the grid!

```
OneFrame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='n')
...
TwoFrame.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='n')
...
ThreeFrame.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='n')
...
FourFrame.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky='n')
...
FiveFrame.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky='n')
...
SixFrame.grid(column=6, row=1, sticky='n')
```

You might also want to add some y-axis padding to the bottom of the 5th frame since it does sort of butt up against the parent frame

```
FiveFrame.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky='n', pady=(0, 5))
```

The first padding number is the top padding and the second is the bottom padding :) Hope that helps!

*Here's how that looks (padding included)*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough "reputation" to simply comment on your question so have no alternative but to post this as an answer.
You have 3 choices - `grid`, `pack`, & `place`.  Pretty sure in this situation you'll have to use `place` to get each of your frames at the same level.

OK, I just ran your code and found a simpler solution than using `place`.  It's a bit of a hack but will do what you're asking.
Change this line
From:

```
FiveFrame.grid(column=5, row=1)
```

To:

```
FiveFrame.grid(column=5, row=1, pady=(22,0))
```

Edit: Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Since you cant mark multiple answers as solutions: thanks! This worked too :)